# Is there a way to cancel nextjs 13 layout?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have the following pages: `/`, `/accounts`, `/signin`

I want to use a dashboard layout for the first 2 and a normal layout for the signin page. But i have no idea how i can achieve this. If i add the dashboard layout to the `layout.tsx` file i see it on the signin page and i can't override it there. If i add the layout to the `page.tsx` file, it kinda defeats the whole purpose of those layouts?

```
export default function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body className="bg-gray-50">{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

vs

```
export default function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body className="bg-gray-50">
        <LayoutComponent />

        <div className="p-4 mt-16 sm:ml-64">{children}</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: If I correctly understand your question, maybe what you're looking for is [Route groups](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#route-groups)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could leave the `/singin` page in the main directory and create an additional directory for dashboard pages, e.g. `app/(dashboard)`, putting `dashboard` in parenthesis means that it won't affect the URL, see [the docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#example-organize-routes-without-affecting-the-url-path).

The structure would look like:

```
- app
  - layout.js <- your main layout
  - singin
    - page.js
  - (dashboard)
    - page.js
    - layout.js <- your dashboard layout
    - accounts
      - page.js
```

Comment: Thanks! This works exactly like i want!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am using this way.

`app/layout.js`

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body className={inter.className}>
                <LayoutProvider>
                   {children}
                </LayoutProvider>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

`LayoutProvider.js`

```
// Use the client directive for using usePathname hook.
'use client'

// Use usePathname for catching route name.
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
import Header from '../Header/Header';
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer';

export const LayoutProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const pathname = usePathname();

    if (pathname === "/account/login") {
        return <>
            {children}
        </>
    }
    else {
        return <>
            <header>
                <Header />
            </header>

            <main>
                {children}
            </main>

            <footer>
                <Footer />
            </footer>
        </>
    }
};
```

Hope it will work for you! <3